# Looker custom dimension, like partition by with SQL

Tags: looker-studio, looker

| Customer id | engaged | engaged_v2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | true | true |
| a | false | true |
| b | false | false |
| c | true | true |
| c | false | true |
| c | false | true |

I attempt to create a custom dimension in Looker. However, I'm struggling to create the `engaged_v2` field which checks the condition whether a customer id has at least one row conforming with `engaged == true`. If this happens then I want `engaged_v2` to be `true` in all rows for that customer id. I am trying to create this in an explorer rather than in the lookml itself.

[image]